# How implement CoreNFC in iOS 14 with swift

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

When im executed the next code in iPhone Xs with iOS 14:

```
   var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?
    session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
    
    session?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near the item to learn more about it."
    session?.begin()
```

I got the following error:

```
[CoreNFC] 00000002 83fe0180 -[NFCNDEFReaderSession _callbackDidBecomeActive]:218  Delegate does not implement -readerSessionDidBecomeActive: method
```

even having implemented the method:

```
func readerSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession) {

}
```

Comment: is this all the code? what delegate methods for `NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate` are implemented?

Comment: func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) and implement  func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error)

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I have tried to encapsulate the whole reader session and delegate into a single class... My problem was that I forgot to hold a strong reference to this new class, so at the time the reader session was started, the delegate had "vanished". Try to use a view controller as your delegate. As long as it displayed the reader session should be able to call your delegate methods.

Comment: @RΛULQUISPE  Are you able to get the solution for that .I am facing the same issue .

Comment: yep use a nfc device not use bluethoot

Comment: Is your issue solved? If not, I can give a try.